# Setting random value for sessionStorage JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is generate a random value for different colors in a `sessionStorage` object and have it stay the same for the duration of the session (until the window is closed).  Here is my code so far:

```
var colorsArray = ["string", "myString", "something"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsArray.length);
var color = colorsArray[randomNumber];

if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    sessionStorage.color = color;
} else {
    console.log("Session storage is not supported");
}

console.log(sessionStorage.color);
```

So, this works as far as saving a random value into the `sessionStorage` object, but it generates a new value each time.  What I want to do is set a value randomly on load and save that value for the duration of the session.  When the browser is closed, it would reset.

My question is, how would I save a randomly generated value into the `sessionStorage` object for the duration of the session and reset it when the browser is closed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one and only one problem with this code:

You keep re-setting the color saved in your sessionStoreage every time you run the page.

You need a line like this:

```
if (sessionStorage.color==null)
  sessionStorage.color = color;
```

Comment: Right you are, sir.  I totally forgot to check to see if a value exists.  Duh.  Thanks!  I got it working now.